# Setting a unique color for each category group in SSRS chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report that has separate charts (both column and pie charts) for each of the 3 past years. The data includes a promotion type as a category group. I'm looking to standardize the coloring so regardless which promotion types are displayed colors match on each of the charts, but some years have promotion types that others do not. There are more than 300 promotion types, and always the possibility of more coming, so using an IIF statement or creating a color palette are probably out of the question.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a way to roll up the category group/promotion type to a higher level so that 300+ unique colors aren't needed? Because, once you get over so many colors, they don't offer any value on a report.

Comment: Very rarely, if ever, will all the promotion types appear on the same report. There is just the possibility that they could all appear. Generally, there are about 40 or fewer per client.

Comment: Okay, that is good. A rollup to a higher lever may still be a good option. Are the colors meant to be meaningful, or just decoration? Not a question I really I need an answer to, but maybe a question to ask the folks using this report.

Answer (score 0):

Have you found 40-50 colors that are distinct enough that you can tell them apart when they are all on screen at the same time?  In my experience, colors become less useful once you get above 10 items as the various shades become hard to distinguish.

Regardless of if it can be done, I don't think the final outcome would be usable.  Too many colors become overwhelming and meaningless to a user.  It is much better to use distinct colors for your top 5 or so and then lump everything together into an 'Other' color.